# How can I set a specific (Content-Type) HTTP response header by configuring undertow?

Tags: wildfly, undertow

### Summary

I'm implementing a web service, that is deployed on a Wildfly-15 application server. I'd like to have the `Content-Type` HTTP response header to include `charset=UTF-8`. This is necessary for the client to understand my response.

### Details

One of my clients always sends its request without specifying charset in `Content-Type`. Wildfly's web service stack in this case uses the default `charset=ISO-8859-1` in the response. See this behavior in undertow [code](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/HttpServerExchange.java), lines 602-611:

```
private String extractCharset(HeaderMap headers) {
    String contentType = headers.getFirst(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (contentType != null) {
        String value = Headers.extractQuotedValueFromHeader(contentType, "charset");
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return ISO_8859_1;
}
```

Because my response is, in fact, `UTF-8`-encoded (and its need to be), this causes trouble on the client side. See the header dumps in the undertow log:

```
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
        header=Connection=Keep-Alive
        header=SOAPAction=****            
        header=Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate
        header=Content-Type=text/xml
        header=Content-Length=2137
        header=User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
        header=Host=****
        locale=[]
        method=POST
        ....
 --------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
        header=Connection=keep-alive
        header=Content-Type=text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
        header=Content-Length=1553
        header=Date=Tue, 29 Jan 2019 16:19:38 GMT
        status=200
```

This kind of response leads to the following exception in an IBM Websphere application:

```
org.springframework.ws.InvalidXmlException: Could not parse XML; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Unfortunately, modifying the client is not an option.

### Unsuccessful experiments

My efforts so far went into trying to configure Widlfy's undertow via specifying filters to override HTTP Response headers. I was able to set `Content-Encoding` only, with the help of *Response Header* filter. It seems, the `Content-Type` header is overridden somewhere else along the line.

My second guess was to use *Expression Filter* with the expression

```
header(header=Content-Type, value='text/xml;charset=UTF-8')
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work also.

### Question

- Can this problem be solved by the configuration of undertow?
- Or should I somehow (how?) programmatically set  the HTTP response header to include `charset=UTF-8`?